# Prolog setof/3 not returning all elements

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

I'm making a list of all the breed of dog sizes in my database, e.g.

```
breed(beagle,medium, hunting).
breed(bassets,medium, hunting).
breed(labrador,large, guideDogs).
breed(germanShepards,large, guardDogs).
breed(boxer,unknown,unknown).
breed(dalmation,unknown,unknown).
breed(ridgeback,unknown,unknown).
```

so I get the sizes from the database, but want to just have the unique sizes so that I can count them later. If I use

```
sizes(List) :- findall(Size, breed(_,Size,_), List).
```

I get duplicates  e.g.
    [medium, medium, large, unknown, unknown, unknown]

setof/3 is meant to make the set unique, so i tried

```
sizes(List) :- setof(Size, breed(_,Size,_), List).
```

but  it now only return the first entry 
    [medium]

Any ideas why??

Comment: Both queries are the same.

Comment: thanks, i have edited it

Comment: Give a minimal set of facts reproducing the issue.

Comment: OK have just added the database that can reproduce the problem

Comment: The problem is the variables in your test condition that you don't care about when using `setof/3`. You need to use the existential quantifier: `setof(Size, Name^Type^breed(Name, Size, Type), List)`. Using `_` doesn't solve that for you because `_` will still be bound. The existential quantifier indicates that you don't wish to bind the variable. See the documentation, for example, [`bagof/3, setof/3`](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog033.html#sec114).

Comment: Do you mean like this?:     sizes(List) :- setof(Size, breed(Type,Size,Job), List).  I still got the same result.

Comment: No. I mean just like I wrote in my previous comment. :) `sizes(List) :- setof(Size, Type^Job^breed(Type,Size,Job), List).` Just using variables without the quantifier gives you the same problem: the variables will be bound and give you multiple, narrower solutions form `setof/3`. See the documentation.

Comment: Doh, awesome thank you